# Помогите написать скрипт, который «нарисует» (выведет на консоль) лестницу (Python)

Tags: python

Необходимо написать скрипт, который «нарисует» (выведет на консоль) лестницу. Количество ступенек в лестнице передается скрипту в качестве параметра. Гарантируется, что на вход подаются только целые числа > 0. Чтение данных нужно произвести способом, аналогичным тому, что описан в предыдущем задании. Ступени должны отображаться с помощью символа решетки  "#" и пробелов. Пример работы скрипта:

```
$ python solution.py 3
  #
 ##
###
$ python solution.py 5
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
$
```

Вывод должен содержать только пробелы и символ "#". Первая строка вывода не должна быть пустой. Строки вывода лестницы не должны содержать лишних пробелов в начале и конце строки. Допускается наличие пустой строки после вывода последней строки, содержащей ступени. Например так:

```
$ python solution.py 5
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####

$
```

Вот код отправленный на тест:

```
import sys
c = int(sys.argv[1])
for x in range(1, c+1):
    print(str(x) + " " * (c - x) + '#' * x)
```

При прохождении теста выдало следующее:
Total tests: 48. Tests failed: 24, Errors: 0. Total time: 5.311.
Failed test - test_2_3[1].
E   AssertionError: Тест 2.3. Вывод должен содержать только пробелы и символы, обозначающие ступеньки: # .
assert ({'#', '1'} == {' ', '#'}
Extra items in the left set:
'1'
Extra items in the right set:
' '
Use -v to get the full diff or {'#', '1'} == {'#'}
Extra items in the left set:
'1'
Use -v to get the full diff)

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вам необходимо, вы и делайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ваш код

```
for x in range(1, c+1):
    print(str(x) + " " * (c - x) + '#' * x)
```

выводит следующее:

```
1    #
2   ##
3  ###
4 ####
5#####
```

не очень похоже на то, что требуется вывести по заданию и на примеры вывода, не находите?

может стоит нумерацию строк убрать при выводе

Comment: "семен семеныч, ну что же вы?" Да, спасибо, точно! А слона то я и не заметил )